# Android Application using eclipse java gives Error

Tags: android

I have an activity and use a Listview, ImageButton, Edittext and Spinner in this Activity. But my problem is that Whenever I run my code, its show the errors..

```
08-11 06:38:38.433: D/dalvikvm(1012): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 133K, 7% free 2745K/2940K, paused 172ms, total 206ms
08-11 06:38:38.713: E/TCP Client(1012): C: Connecting...
08-11 06:38:38.723: D/AndroidRuntime(1012): Shutting down VM
08-11 06:38:38.723: W/dalvikvm(1012): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android_examples.com.tabhost/com.android_examples.com.tabhost.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android_examples.com.tabhost/com.android_examples.com.tabhost.TabActivity_1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android_examples.com.tabhost/com.android_examples.com.tabhost.TabActivity_1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2054)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at com.android_examples.com.tabhost.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     ... 11 more
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at com.android_examples.com.tabhost.TabActivity_1.onCreate(TabActivity_1.java:50)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-11 06:38:38.973: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     ... 21 more
08-11 06:38:46.273: I/Process(1012): Sending signal. PID: 1012 SIG: 9
```

My Activity Code is..

```
public  class TabActivity_1 extends Activity {
private ListView mList;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;
private TCPClient mTcpClient;
Spinner sp1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_activity_1);

    sp1=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ar=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Type1,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    ar.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    sp1.setAdapter(ar);

     arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

     final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        ImageButton startt = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        //relate the listView from java to the one created in xml
        mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, arrayList);
        mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // connect to the server
        new connectTask().execute("");

       startt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String message = editText.getText().toString();

                //add the text in the arrayList
                arrayList.add("c: " + message);

                //refresh the list
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                editText.setText("");
            }
        });
}

        public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TCPClient> {

            @Override
            protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

                //we create a TCPClient object and
                mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                    @Override
                    //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                    public void messageReceived(String message) {
                        //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                        publishProgress(message);
                    }
                });
                mTcpClient.run();

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);

                //in the arrayList we add the messaged received from server
                arrayList.add(values[0]);
                // notify the adapter that the data set has changed. This means that new message received
                // from server was added to the list
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }            

         public void buttonClickMethod(View v){
              Intent i= new Intent(TabActivity_1.this,PageAjout.class);
              startActivity(i);
          }
        }
```

I'm confused, where I am doing wrong. Guide me.

Comment: Which line exactly?

Comment: Please don't post errors as images. Also describe the issue in more detail.

Comment: Are you sure that you have initialised Edit-text properly?

Comment: please put tabActivity_1 code 
beause this error come when u forgot any inalization like edirText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);or check same for startt also

Comment: debug debug debug ...... and please update your logcate and code also here

Comment: You haven't pasted enough of the logcat. The cause is further down the stack. Post the entire stacktrace in the question as text.

Answer (score 0):

You set empty arrayList to adapter that's why the code gives NullPointerException.

Remove the code from `onCreate()`

```
mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, arrayList);
mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

and override `onPostExecute()` method of `AsyncTask` and set arrayList to adapter. You can also put a condition for check if arrayList should not be null.

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
      super.onProgressUpdate(values);

       //in the arrayList we add the messaged received from server
      arrayList.add(values[0]);
}
protected void onPostExecute (TCPClient result) {
     mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, arrayList);
     mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Hope it helps.